# SSRS Report Builder Display a Column of Class within Class wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, reporting-services, report, ssrs-2008

I have class `DepositItem` and in `DepositItem` class has one field with Doctor(class).how can i Display a column of `Doctor.Name` in Table of Report Builder.I was create DepositData

```
public class DepositItem  {

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public DoctorItem Doctor { get; set; }

    public decimal Amount { get; set; }

    public DepositItem() { }

}
public class DoctorDNormItem {

    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DoctorDNormItem() { }

}
```

this is how i set DataSet of DepositItem class

```
            object[] objs = { caseExpense.Deposite };
            var dt = ToDataTable<DepositItem>(caseExpense.Deposite.ToList());
            ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
            reportDataSource.Name = "DepositeDataSet";
            reportDataSource.Value = dt;
            _report.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
```

Inthis Image Table of Report ssrs  i set Doctor and i goes error beacause it is object not a datatype property, i want to set Doctor.Name there.

[image]

Any Help will be appreciated.